# How to place an image on top left of another image without using Javascript?

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image in the center of a div

[image]

The image is centered in the parent div using the following css:

```
img { margin:0px auto; }
```

The image can have arbitrary dimensions.

How can I position the Magnifying Glass (zoom) image on top left of the image without using Javascript, while the main image can have any width or height?

Comment: If you do not want to use JS, the only way to do it with CSS is to have the `<img>` element pre-wrapped with another element, like `<div>` or `<figure>`, or even `<picture>`, so that you can position the magnifying class relative to the image element. However, this requires modifying the DOM, which either requires manual updating your file, or relying on JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `position:relative` and `position:absolute`. Look at the following HTML and CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="test"><img src="http://isc.stuorg.iastate.edu/wp-content/uploads/sample.jpg" border="0" />
    <img src="http://www.beyotta.net/images/icon_magnifier.png" border="0" class="absimg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {width:100%; height:400px; border:1px solid blue; text-align:center;}
.test
{  
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.absimg
{
position:absolute;
top:5px;
left:5px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jukunh71/)

Answer (score 1):

Giving a position relative to the image and absolute to the magnifying glass image would do the trick here's the demo on what I've done.

http://jsbin.com/yumelamive/5/edit?html,css,output

Comment: it is not the case you are thinking.

Comment: I thought this would do it for you because it seems ideal.

Comment: An answer should contain relevant code in the answer itself, not just linked. But it is difficult to see what in the approach does not meet the requirements. @AbdulBasit, if this is “not the case”, what *is* your case?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure it will work or not but try using before will help

```
img:before {
    content: 'img/zoom.png ';
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

for proper help atleast provide a jsfiddle or code of your work

Comment: The `<img>` element is [empty based on W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html), so it will also not accept any pseudo-elements such as `::before` and `::after`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Use this

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/dpub9f78/)

```
div{
content:"";
display:block;
height:300px;
width:300px; 
border:solid 1px #CCCCCC;
background-image: url("http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg");
position: absolute;    
}
div:before {
content:"";
background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icontexto/search/48/search-red-icon.png"); 
top:0;
left:0;
position:absolute;
width: 40px;
height: 48px;
}
```

Comment: first thing i can not restrict the width and height of the div and the second is image should be placed inside the page as it is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

I would make a div for the image, set the background the image and add:

position: relative;

for that div. Then put the magnifying glass within the div and set:

position: absolute: top: 0; left: 0;

.image {
  background: url(eiffel.jpg);
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;}
.image img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0:}

The 'relative' is what any 'absolute' objects..relate to.

I hope that helps.

Comment: well the problem is i can not restrict the width and height of the parent div as well as image.

Comment: You could set the dimensions of the div to the element: style="width: 100px;height: 200px;" or just write both images into the div?

Answer (score 0):

set the image Magnifying Glass to `absolute:position`and use `left: right:` for right position then the parent div set to `position:relative`